# How to integrate Dotnetnuke wesite with existing website

Tags: asp.net, iis, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-settings

Perhaps I'm not thinking clearly but I have an existing website/application that I want to "front-end" with DNN without re-writing the application in DNN's modular format, i.e; I want DNN to handle membership, authentication, etc. Authenticated users could then access my existing web application.

There are a couple articles here that discuss what it might look like when integrated and some discuss the pitfalls that might be associated with such an arrangement, however none of the articles outline the steps I would need to take to deploy DNN this way.

I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to setup child sites  or even parent site in DNN host management that will successfully point to my existing application. It errors out because it's looking for all the DNN libraries.

When I try adding adding a virtual application/directory in the DNN site definition (IIS) that points to my existing web app, I get DNN's error page stating the page doesn't exist.

I don't want to rewrite the application as a module, but if someone would be kind enough to walk me through the steps of setting the two websites up so they can share membership information, I would be terribly grateful. What would I need to setup in IIS, DNN, and my existing website.

Thank You...
C. Lane

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much won't, you can have DNN running side by side with another application running, or you can convert content/modules/functionality into DNN.

If you want to share membership, you'll have to code your application to use the DNN authencation/users/profiles, but there aren't any step by steps for that.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I went ahead and ported to separate DNN Modules. That part wasn't difficult really, however, reformatting all the stylesheets  is going to be a.... Thanks!

Comment: I would start by looking at an existing skin, my Bootstrap one is a good start if you want to use Bootstrap https://github.com/ChrisHammond/HammerFlex

Comment: LOVE Bootstrap! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question actually comes up pretty frequently.  An easy solution would be to have both applications use AD authentication.  Probably not the solution you are looking for but its the simplest.

I've never tried it, but if they are both using SqlMembershipAuthentication, you might be able to configure both to point to the same database (the dnnDB).  Check this link for [SqlMembership configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I'm sure DNN wouldn't support this, but it could work,... I think.